# PHP imap_open(): invalid remote specification when trying connect to GMAIL

Tags: php, imap

I'm trying to retrive mails from Gmail and got following error:

```
Can't open mailbox {imap.gmail.com:993/imap/ssl/novalidate-cert}INBOX: invalid remote specification
```

OpenSSL and IMAP are installed in my server, following are openssl & imap info from phpinfo();

```
openssl
OpenSSL support enabled
OpenSSL Library Version OpenSSL 0.9.7l 28 Sep 2006
OpenSSL Header Version

imap

IMAP c-Client Version   2007e
Kerberos Support    enabled
```

I'm really confused now, please help!

Comment: I would look for [`imap_errors`](http://php.net/manual/en/function.imap-errors.php) and maybe alerts. However if this is on the network layer (hint: SSL), you might need an update for your SSL libs.

Answer (score 4):

I have been having a similar issue. I can tell you from personal experience that while you may have IMAP and OpenSSL installed, you may need to recompile php install "--with-imap-ssl[=DIR]." I wanted to do the same thing and received the same error. I also had the same OpenSSL and IMAP versions installed. I have recompiled php, and here is my config:

> ./configure --prefix=/usr/local/apache2/php --with-imap=/usr/local/imap-2007f/ --with-curl=/usr/local/curl/  --enable-sockets --with-imap-ssl=/usr/local/ssl --with-openssl --with-apxs2=/usr/local/apache2/bin/apxs --with-kerberos --without-iconv

You don't need to use the same config of course, because it is customized for what I need.

In case you are unfamiliar with compiling php, you can find the source here:
http://www.php.net/downloads.php
Here's a basic tutorial on how to compile php and apache, assuming you are on UNIX. It also includes how to compile them with curl, you can use all of the instructions for curl and replace them with ssl and imap respectively and it should work.
http://thermo.sdsu.edu/testhome/phpinstall.html

Comment: Fixed the issue I was having - had OpenSSL as well as imap enabled, but was still getting the error. Re-compiled php --with-imap-ssl and is working now.

Answer (score 2):

For Docker I learned that this error occurs when calling `docker-php-ext-install` *before* `docker-php-ext-configure`, which I did by mistake. So the `RUN` directive in the `Dockerfile` must look like this:

```
FROM php:8-fpm-alpine
# ...
RUN apk add imap-dev openssl-dev \
    && docker-php-ext-configure imap --with-imap --with-imap-ssl \
    && docker-php-ext-install imap
```

instead of

```
RUN apk add imap-dev openssl-dev \
    && docker-php-ext-install imap \
    && docker-php-ext-configure imap --with-imap --with-imap-ssl
```

Otherwise, the imap extension seems to be installed - calls like `function_exists('imap_open')` will return true. But all calls to `imap_open`
will fail with the mentioned error:

> invalid remote specification

Even if it's a correct remote specification which has  been widely prooven like `{imap.gmail.com:993/imap/ssl/novalidate-cert/norsh}INBOX` or `{imap.gmail.com:993/imap/ssl}INBOX` from e.g. [this article](https://www.geeksforgeeks.org/how-to-get-emails-using-php-and-imap/). So make sure that you first configure and then install the extension.

Comment: Thank you! This worked after a lot of other places led me to something that did not.

Answer (score 0):

```
 $iconnect = imap_open("{imap.gmail.com:993/ssl/novalidate-cert}INBOX","user@gmail.com","passwordofuser") or die(imap_errors());
```

Check this code this will connect to gmail server .