# Setting up gmail with imap in PHP on Mac using MAMP PRO

Tags: php, gmail, imap, mamp

I've been trying to use PHP to access gmail but I can't get it to work.

I'm not sure if it's MAMP PRO's issue. I'm using MAMP PRO 2.0.3

Here is my code:

```
$server="{imap.gmail.com:993/imap/ssl/novalidate-cert}INBOX";
$inbox = imap_open($server,$username,$password) or die('Cannot connect to Gmail: ' . imap_last_error());
```

And the error I got was:

```
PHP Notice:  Unknown: Can't open mailbox {imap.gmail.com:993/imap/ssl/novalidate-cert}INBOX: invalid remote specification (errflg=2) in Unknown on line 0
```

Comment: Possibly a firewall issue? have a look at this question: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/10582984/workaround-for-php-imap-functions-trying-to-work-with-incoming-email-on-localho

Comment: I don't have any firewall on my Mac

Answer (score 1, accepted):

After some research, I have found out that MAMP PRO doesn't have imap-ssl installed and therefore it cannot connect to gmail server since it requires ssl.

Instead, used PHPMailer library.