# php imap_open giving issues connecting

Tags: php, macos, ssl, imap-open

I am having some issues with `imap_open`.
This is the error I am getting:

> Message: imap_open(): Couldn't open stream
>   {imap-mail.outlook.com:993/imap/ssl/novalidate-cert}INBOX

No matter if its imap using ssl on port 993 or pop ssl on port 995, I am getting the same error.

Message:

> Unknown: Can't open mailbox
>   {imap-mail.outlook.com:993/imap/ssl/novalidate-cert}INBOX: invalid
>   remote specification (errflg=2)

I have the following setup:

Mac OSX Yosemite
Mamp Pro running PHP 5.6.10

Here is what I've done to troubleshoot:

1. I have apple mail setup to check my gmail account using imap ssl on port 993. I will assume if apple mail can retrieve mail, the port is open.
2. I went to Security and Privacy and did a PORT SCAN... 993 and 995 were not open... strange.
3. I do not have Mac Firewall enabled.
4. When using non ssl, on port 110 pop, this appears to be working fine.

Can anyone assist to see what may be the cause.

Answer (score 0):

Check phpinfo() to see if php is complied --with-imap-ssl
http://www.bartvanasselt.nl/mamp-pro-using-imap-with-ssl/

Also can try tunneling:
[Workaround for PHP IMAP functions? Trying to work with incoming email on localhost using XAMPP](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10582984/workaround-for-php-imap-functions-trying-to-work-with-incoming-email-on-localho)